# android - kotlin infix not working on one parameter extension function

Tags: android, function, kotlin, infix-notation, kotlin-extension

take a look at this simple extension function i have infix:

```
infix fun View.isValidColor(hexColor: String?): Boolean {
    var isValid = true
    return hexColor?.let {
        try {
            Color.parseColor(it)
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            isValid = false
        }
        isValid
    } ?: false
}

//notice how i have infix the extension meaning brackets are not needed, hopefully making it easier to read.
```

Now lets see the usage and what i have tried:

[image]

its not being infix and it follows the [rule for infix](https://medium.com/@agrawalsuneet/infix-notation-kotlin-c3f0786cadb3) that:

1. Must be member functions or extension functions.
2. They must have a single parameter.
3. The parameter must not accept a variable number of arguments and must have no default value.

what am i doing wrong ?

UPDATE:
I ALSO tried this but its working by explicitly calling the referring class:
[image]

since now im using the explicit object why did it fail ? ivLogo is a ImageView synthetic from kotlin.

Comment: `Note that infix functions always require both the receiver and the parameter to be specified. When you're calling a method on the current receiver using the infix notation, you need to use this explicitly; unlike regular method calls, it cannot be omitted. This is required to ensure unambiguous parsing.` - quote from the docs and also mentioned in your link

Comment: i posted a update, so now i tried calling it with the view itself.  should be similar to saying this.isValidColor "#fffff" right ? but it still fails. how would you go about this ?

Comment: There should not be a dot between object and the function

Comment: Actually I am not sure if `isValidColor` is a good infix function. I would go with a plain function instead.

Comment: its working now , thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make **infix** function work, to the left of it should be placed an actual instance of object:

```
val result = someView isValidColor "#FFFFFF"
```